# Blank (no signal) display on new ASUS Z590 motherboard

Tags: graphics, display, intel

If I interrupt grub and select recovery mode, then resume normal boot, I get a working but unsatisfactory low-resolution display.

Motherboard BIOS version: 0232 x64 01/06/2021

Other things to note, I have upgraded to the latest kernel and the latest Mesa.

Looking at most other question threads, I will try to include as much info as I can:

lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:        20.10
Codename:       groovy
```

uname -a

```
Linux ubuntu-13 5.10.0-051000-generic #202012132330 SMP Sun Dec 13 23:33:36 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

sudo lspci -vk | grep -A 15 VGA

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9bc5 (rev 05) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        DeviceName: Onboard - Video
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
        Memory at 6000000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
        Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
        Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
        Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
        Kernel modules: i915
```

sudo lsmod | grep i9

```
i915                 2326528  0
drm_kms_helper        233472  1 i915
cec                    53248  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
drm                   548864  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
video                  49152  2 asus_wmi,i915
```

glxinfo | grep Mesa

```
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
    Vendor: Mesa/X.org (0xffffffff)
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa/X.org
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 21.1.0-devel (git-b4d1764 2021-03-05 groovy-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 21.1.0-devel (git-b4d1764 2021-03-05 groovy-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 21.1.0-devel (git-b4d1764 2021-03-05 groovy-oibaf-ppa)
```

xrandr --display :1

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*
```

lspci -nn

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9b33] (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9bc5] (rev 05)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43ed] (rev 11)
00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43ef] (rev 11)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43e8] (rev 11)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43e9] (rev 11)
00:15.2 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43ea] (rev 11)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43e0] (rev 11)
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43d2] (rev 11)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43c0] (rev 11)
00:1b.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43c2] (rev 11)
00:1b.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43c3] (rev 11)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43b8] (rev 11)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43b0] (rev 11)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4385] (rev 11)
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:f0c8] (rev 11)
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43a3] (rev 11)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43a4] (rev 11)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Intel(R) Ethernet Controller I225-V [8086:15f3] (rev 03)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
```

inxi

```
CPU: 10-Core Intel Core i9-10850K (-MT MCP-) speed/min/max: 800/800/5200 MHz Kernel: 5.10.0-051000-generic x86_64 Up: 41m
Mem: 819.0/15817.1 MiB (5.2%) Storage: 931.51 GiB (2.4% used) Procs: 367 Shell: Bash inxi: 3.1.07
```

inxi -G --display

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel driver: N/A
  Display: x11 server: X.org 1.20.9 driver: fbdev unloaded: modesetting,vesa
  Message: No advanced graphics data found on this system.
```

sudo dmesg | grep i915

```
[   17.744662] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: No i915 binding for Intel HDMI/DP codec
```

cat /proc/cmdline

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-051000-generic root=UUID=2d091cb5-9a6c-4533-bbe4-9619f25a9740 ro quiet splash i915.alpha_support=1 vt.handoff=7
```

In case anyone is still watching this, here is what seems to be the relevant sections of /var/log/syslog from a failed boot:

```
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.518570] i915: unknown parameter 'alpha_support' ignored
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.518928] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.518928] i915 0000:00:02.0: drm_WARN_ON(!IS_PLATFORM(dev_priv, INTEL_TIGERLAKE) && !IS_PLATFORM(dev_priv, INTEL_ROCKETLAKE))
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.518961] WARNING: CPU: 16 PID: 509 at drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_pch.c:123 intel_pch_type+0x8a0/0x960 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.518962] Modules linked in: i915(+) soundwire_bus drm_kms_helper iwlmvm(+) cec mac80211 rc_core libarc4 snd_soc_core i2c_algo_bit snd_usb_audio(+) fb_sys_fops snd_usbmidi_lib snd_hwdep mc syscopyarea snd_compress sysfillrect input_leds ac97_bus sysimgblt snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq btusb mei_hdcp snd_seq_device snd_timer btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth iwlwifi snd ecdh_generic ecc soundcore asus_nb_wmi eeepc_wmi asus_wmi sparse_keymap mac_hid cfg80211 mei_me mei ee1004 rapl intel_cstate wmi_bmof acpi_pad acpi_tad intel_wmi_thunderbolt efi_pstore sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid crc32_pclmul intel_lpss_pci i2c_i801 igc ahci intel_lpss i2c_smbus idma64 xhci_pci libahci virt_dma xhci_pci_renesas wmi video pinctrl_tigerlake
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.518985] CPU: 16 PID: 509 Comm: systemd-udevd Not tainted 5.10.0-051000-generic #202012132330
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.518986] Hardware name: ASUS System Product Name/ROG STRIX Z590-A GAMING WIFI, BIOS 0232 01/06/2021
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519008] RIP: 0010:intel_pch_type+0x8a0/0x960 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519010] Code: 4c 8b 67 50 4d 85 e4 75 03 4c 8b 27 e8 19 cf 09 d4 48 c7 c1 78 be a9 c0 4c 89 e2 48 c7 c7 7a 45 ac c0 48 89 c6 e8 37 fa 49 d4 <0f> 0b e9 17 f9 ff ff 48 8b 7b 18 4c 8b 67 50 4d 85 e4 75 03 4c 8b
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519010] RSP: 0018:ffffa35d812c7a20 EFLAGS: 00010282
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519011] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8c9a87660000 RCX: ffff8c9dcc418a48
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519012] RDX: 00000000ffffffd8 RSI: 0000000000000027 RDI: ffff8c9dcc418a40
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519012] RBP: ffffa35d812c7a30 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffffa35d812c7800
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519013] R10: ffffa35d812c77f8 R11: ffffffff95f52ca8 R12: ffff8c9a81cf6e60
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519013] R13: ffff8c9a87660000 R14: 0000000000004380 R15: 0000000000000042
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519014] FS:  00007feae898c8c0(0000) GS:ffff8c9dcc400000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519015] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519015] CR2: 00007f75d87b0850 CR3: 000000010923c001 CR4: 00000000007706e0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519016] PKRU: 55555554
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519016] Call Trace:
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519039]  intel_detect_pch+0x65/0x1a0 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519060]  i915_driver_early_probe+0x1a5/0x250 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519081]  i915_driver_probe+0xaa/0x300 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519083]  ? mutex_lock+0x13/0x40
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519086]  ? acpi_dev_found+0x66/0x70
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519106]  i915_pci_probe+0x58/0x140 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519109]  local_pci_probe+0x48/0x80
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519110]  pci_call_probe+0x53/0xf0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519111]  pci_device_probe+0xad/0xf0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519112]  really_probe+0x221/0x490
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519113]  driver_probe_device+0xe9/0x160
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519114]  device_driver_attach+0xab/0xb0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519115]  __driver_attach+0x8f/0x150
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519116]  ? device_driver_attach+0xb0/0xb0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519117]  bus_for_each_dev+0x7e/0xc0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519118]  driver_attach+0x1e/0x20
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519119]  bus_add_driver+0x135/0x1f0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519120]  driver_register+0x91/0xf0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519121]  __pci_register_driver+0x54/0x60
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519143]  i915_init+0x61/0x75 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519144]  ? 0xffffffffc0b42000
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519146]  do_one_initcall+0x48/0x1d0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519148]  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0xf6/0x200
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519149]  ? do_init_module+0x28/0x270
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519151]  do_init_module+0x62/0x270
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519152]  load_module+0x68d/0x710
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519153]  __do_sys_finit_module+0xc2/0x120
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519155]  __x64_sys_finit_module+0x1a/0x20
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519156]  do_syscall_64+0x38/0x90
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519157]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519158] RIP: 0033:0x7feae8e4267d
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519159] Code: 00 c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa 48 89 f8 48 89 f7 48 89 d6 48 89 ca 4d 89 c2 4d 89 c8 4c 8b 4c 24 08 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d bb f7 0c 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519159] RSP: 002b:00007ffe8c551c18 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519160] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055d172c142a0 RCX: 00007feae8e4267d
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519161] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 000055d172a51660 RDI: 0000000000000016
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519161] RBP: 0000000000020000 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519162] R10: 0000000000000016 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 000055d172a51660
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519162] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 000055d1729e1fc0 R15: 000055d172c142a0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519163] ---[ end trace d9260bb2ec79d9de ]---
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519600] checking generic (4000000000 300000) vs hw (6000000000 1000000)
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519601] checking generic (4000000000 300000) vs hw (4000000000 10000000)
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519601] fb0: switching to inteldrmfb from EFI VGA
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519647] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.519667] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521027] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521561] mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521889] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* crtc 51: Can't calculate constants, dotclock = 0!
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521894] ------------[ cut here ]------------
```

More:

```
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521894] i915 0000:00:02.0: drm_WARN_ON_ONCE(drm_drv_uses_atomic_modeset(dev))
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521920] WARNING: CPU: 16 PID: 509 at drivers/gpu/drm/drm_vblank.c:722 drm_crtc_vblank_helper_get_vblank_timestamp_internal+0x333/0x340 [drm]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521920] Modules linked in: i915(+) soundwire_bus drm_kms_helper iwlmvm(+) cec mac80211 rc_core libarc4 snd_soc_core i2c_algo_bit snd_usb_audio(+) fb_sys_fops snd_usbmidi_lib snd_hwdep mc syscopyarea snd_compress sysfillrect input_leds ac97_bus sysimgblt snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq btusb mei_hdcp snd_seq_device snd_timer btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth iwlwifi snd ecdh_generic ecc soundcore asus_nb_wmi eeepc_wmi asus_wmi sparse_keymap mac_hid cfg80211 mei_me mei ee1004 rapl intel_cstate wmi_bmof acpi_pad acpi_tad intel_wmi_thunderbolt efi_pstore sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid crc32_pclmul intel_lpss_pci i2c_i801 igc ahci intel_lpss i2c_smbus idma64 xhci_pci libahci virt_dma xhci_pci_renesas wmi video pinctrl_tigerlake
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521944] CPU: 16 PID: 509 Comm: systemd-udevd Tainted: G        W         5.10.0-051000-generic #202012132330
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521944] Hardware name: ASUS System Product Name/ROG STRIX Z590-A GAMING WIFI, BIOS 0232 01/06/2021
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521952] RIP: 0010:drm_crtc_vblank_helper_get_vblank_timestamp_internal+0x333/0x340 [drm]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521953] Code: 4c 8b 6f 50 4d 85 ed 75 03 4c 8b 2f e8 d6 0a 6c d4 48 c7 c1 c8 e2 31 c0 4c 89 ea 48 c7 c7 e8 9c 31 c0 48 89 c6 e8 f4 35 ac d4 <0f> 0b e9 d5 fe ff ff e8 b1 f3 b1 d4 90 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 8b 87
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521954] RSP: 0018:ffffa35d812c7870 EFLAGS: 00010082
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521954] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8c9a87660000 RCX: ffff8c9dcc418a48
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521955] RDX: 00000000ffffffd8 RSI: 0000000000000027 RDI: ffff8c9dcc418a40
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521955] RBP: ffffa35d812c78e8 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffffa35d812c7650
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521956] R10: ffffa35d812c7648 R11: ffffffff95f52ca8 R12: 0000000000000000
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521956] R13: ffff8c9a81cf6e60 R14: ffffffffc090ba60 R15: ffff8c9a8660eca8
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521957] FS:  00007feae898c8c0(0000) GS:ffff8c9dcc400000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521958] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521958] CR2: 00007f75d87b0850 CR3: 000000010923c001 CR4: 00000000007706e0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521959] PKRU: 55555554
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521959] Call Trace:
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521982]  intel_crtc_get_vblank_timestamp+0x18/0x20 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521990]  drm_get_last_vbltimestamp+0xad/0xc0 [drm]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.521997]  drm_reset_vblank_timestamp+0x63/0xd0 [drm]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522004]  drm_crtc_vblank_on+0x85/0x140 [drm]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522034]  intel_modeset_setup_hw_state+0x1af/0x5b0 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522042]  ? drm_modeset_lock_all_ctx+0x137/0x300 [drm]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522049]  ? drm_warn_on_modeset_not_all_locked.part.0+0x5e/0x90 [drm]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522078]  intel_modeset_init_nogem+0x24e/0x490 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522100]  ? intel_irq_postinstall+0x24f/0x290 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522122]  i915_driver_probe+0x11e/0x300 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522123]  ? mutex_lock+0x13/0x40
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522124]  ? acpi_dev_found+0x66/0x70
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522146]  i915_pci_probe+0x58/0x140 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522148]  local_pci_probe+0x48/0x80
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522149]  pci_call_probe+0x53/0xf0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522150]  pci_device_probe+0xad/0xf0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522151]  really_probe+0x221/0x490
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522152]  driver_probe_device+0xe9/0x160
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522153]  device_driver_attach+0xab/0xb0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522154]  __driver_attach+0x8f/0x150
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522155]  ? device_driver_attach+0xb0/0xb0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522157]  bus_for_each_dev+0x7e/0xc0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522157]  driver_attach+0x1e/0x20
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522158]  bus_add_driver+0x135/0x1f0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522159]  driver_register+0x91/0xf0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522160]  __pci_register_driver+0x54/0x60
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522182]  i915_init+0x61/0x75 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522183]  ? 0xffffffffc0b42000
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522184]  do_one_initcall+0x48/0x1d0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522185]  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0xf6/0x200
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522187]  ? do_init_module+0x28/0x270
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522188]  do_init_module+0x62/0x270
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522189]  load_module+0x68d/0x710
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522190]  __do_sys_finit_module+0xc2/0x120
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522192]  __x64_sys_finit_module+0x1a/0x20
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522193]  do_syscall_64+0x38/0x90
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522194]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522194] RIP: 0033:0x7feae8e4267d
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522195] Code: 00 c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa 48 89 f8 48 89 f7 48 89 d6 48 89 ca 4d 89 c2 4d 89 c8 4c 8b 4c 24 08 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d bb f7 0c 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522196] RSP: 002b:00007ffe8c551c18 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522197] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055d172c142a0 RCX: 00007feae8e4267d
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522197] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 000055d172a51660 RDI: 0000000000000016
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522198] RBP: 0000000000020000 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522198] R10: 0000000000000016 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 000055d172a51660
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522199] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 000055d1729e1fc0 R15: 000055d172c142a0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.522200] ---[ end trace d9260bb2ec79d9df ]---
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523071] ------------[ cut here ]------------
```

Still more:

```
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523072] i915 0000:00:02.0: drm_WARN_ON(!pll->info->funcs->get_hw_state(dev_priv, pll, &pipe_config->dpll_hw_state))
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523107] WARNING: CPU: 16 PID: 509 at drivers/gpu/drm/i915/display/intel_display.c:11161 hsw_get_ddi_port_state+0x237/0x260 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523108] Modules linked in: i915(+) soundwire_bus drm_kms_helper iwlmvm(+) cec mac80211 rc_core libarc4 snd_soc_core i2c_algo_bit snd_usb_audio(+) fb_sys_fops snd_usbmidi_lib snd_hwdep mc syscopyarea snd_compress sysfillrect input_leds ac97_bus sysimgblt snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq btusb mei_hdcp snd_seq_device snd_timer btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth iwlwifi snd ecdh_generic ecc soundcore asus_nb_wmi eeepc_wmi asus_wmi sparse_keymap mac_hid cfg80211 mei_me mei ee1004 rapl intel_cstate wmi_bmof acpi_pad acpi_tad intel_wmi_thunderbolt efi_pstore sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid crc32_pclmul intel_lpss_pci i2c_i801 igc ahci intel_lpss i2c_smbus idma64 xhci_pci libahci virt_dma xhci_pci_renesas wmi video pinctrl_tigerlake
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523131] CPU: 16 PID: 509 Comm: systemd-udevd Tainted: G        W         5.10.0-051000-generic #202012132330
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523131] Hardware name: ASUS System Product Name/ROG STRIX Z590-A GAMING WIFI, BIOS 0232 01/06/2021
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523161] RIP: 0010:hsw_get_ddi_port_state+0x237/0x260 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523162] Code: 8b 7b 18 4c 8b 7f 50 4d 85 ff 74 38 e8 42 ea fe d3 48 c7 c1 90 71 aa c0 4c 89 fa 48 c7 c7 66 95 ac c0 48 89 c6 e8 60 15 3f d4 <0f> 0b e9 94 fe ff ff 4c 89 e2 44 89 ee 48 89 df e8 f4 77 fe ff e9
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523162] RSP: 0018:ffffa35d812c7740 EFLAGS: 00010286
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523163] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8c9a87660000 RCX: ffff8c9dcc418a48
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523164] RDX: 00000000ffffffd8 RSI: 0000000000000027 RDI: ffff8c9dcc418a40
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523164] RBP: ffffa35d812c7768 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffffa35d812c7520
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523165] R10: ffffa35d812c7518 R11: ffffffff95f52ca8 R12: ffff8c9a86bed000
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523165] R13: 0000000000000003 R14: ffff8c9a80e9a000 R15: ffff8c9a81cf6e60
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523166] FS:  00007feae898c8c0(0000) GS:ffff8c9dcc400000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523166] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523167] CR2: 00007f75d87b0850 CR3: 000000010923c001 CR4: 00000000007706e0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523167] PKRU: 55555554
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523168] Call Trace:
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523197]  hsw_get_pipe_config+0xfe/0x500 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523220]  ? intel_runtime_pm_put_unchecked+0x33/0x40 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523249]  ? intel_display_power_put_unchecked+0x42/0x50 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523277]  ? skl_ddi_pll_get_hw_state+0xb9/0x110 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523305]  ? verify_single_dpll_state+0xa3/0x350 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523332]  ? verify_wm_state+0x38/0x2f0 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523360]  verify_crtc_state+0x107/0x3c0 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523387]  ? intel_post_plane_update+0xcd/0x1d0 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523414]  intel_atomic_commit_tail+0x3e1/0x610 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523441]  intel_atomic_commit+0x344/0x3c0 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523449]  drm_atomic_commit+0x4a/0x50 [drm]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523476]  intel_initial_commit+0xf5/0x190 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523503]  intel_modeset_init+0x22/0x80 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523525]  i915_driver_probe+0x140/0x300 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523526]  ? mutex_lock+0x13/0x40
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523527]  ? acpi_dev_found+0x66/0x70
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523549]  i915_pci_probe+0x58/0x140 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523550]  local_pci_probe+0x48/0x80
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523551]  pci_call_probe+0x53/0xf0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523552]  pci_device_probe+0xad/0xf0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523553]  really_probe+0x221/0x490
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523554]  driver_probe_device+0xe9/0x160
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523555]  device_driver_attach+0xab/0xb0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523556]  __driver_attach+0x8f/0x150
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523557]  ? device_driver_attach+0xb0/0xb0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523558]  bus_for_each_dev+0x7e/0xc0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523559]  driver_attach+0x1e/0x20
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523560]  bus_add_driver+0x135/0x1f0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523561]  driver_register+0x91/0xf0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523561]  __pci_register_driver+0x54/0x60
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523583]  i915_init+0x61/0x75 [i915]
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523584]  ? 0xffffffffc0b42000
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523585]  do_one_initcall+0x48/0x1d0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523586]  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0xf6/0x200
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523587]  ? do_init_module+0x28/0x270
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523588]  do_init_module+0x62/0x270
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523589]  load_module+0x68d/0x710
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523591]  __do_sys_finit_module+0xc2/0x120
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523592]  __x64_sys_finit_module+0x1a/0x20
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523593]  do_syscall_64+0x38/0x90
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523594]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523595] RIP: 0033:0x7feae8e4267d
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523596] Code: 00 c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa 48 89 f8 48 89 f7 48 89 d6 48 89 ca 4d 89 c2 4d 89 c8 4c 8b 4c 24 08 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d bb f7 0c 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523596] RSP: 002b:00007ffe8c551c18 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523597] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055d172c142a0 RCX: 00007feae8e4267d
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523598] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 000055d172a51660 RDI: 0000000000000016
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523598] RBP: 0000000000020000 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523599] R10: 0000000000000016 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 000055d172a51660
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523599] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 000055d1729e1fc0 R15: 000055d172c142a0
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523600] ---[ end trace d9260bb2ec79d9e0 ]---
Mar 20 15:36:33 ubuntu-13 kernel: [   15.523605] ------------[ cut here ]------------
```

There's a bit more, but there is not enough room in this question for it.  Ask in the comments and I can supply it.

Comment: Your video driver appears to not be installed or not in use. Try `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Comment: No drivers found for installation.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel` and see if it installs

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
xserver-xorg-video-intel is already the newest version (2:2.99.917+git20200714-1).
xserver-xorg-video-intel set to manually installed. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the output of `cat /etc/default/grub` and `sudo dmesg | grep i915`

Comment: Done.  Note that all of the above commands were executed in the context of the recovery mode/resume normal boot "grub mode".  I have installed ssh and can get into the box in the "failed display" state but some of the commands do not work from there.

Comment: Do you have older kernels in grub boot menu? Can you boot to a different kernel? Try booting to an older kernel and see if the issue resolves. Have you upgraded from an older Ubuntu release recently? If yes, was this issue existing on the older release?

Comment: Your kernel seems newer than what I would expect for Ubuntu 20.10 and this might have something to do with your issue.

Comment: Yes, I have the original kernel in the grub menu.  Quick history: I did a clean install of Gorilla from a USB drive.  The USB drive boot behaved the same way but I decided to go ahead and install and fix it once it was installed.  ASUS claims that any required linux drivers are installed in the kernel by Intel.  As part of my attempt to fix it, I installed the latest kernel and Mesa but that did not make any difference.  The Z590 is one of Intel's latest chipsets and it may just not work (yet).

Comment: OK, if ASUS say it is supported then try two things. 1. add `i915.alpha_support=1
` as a kernel parameter during boot just in case the kernel support for this card is still alpha and see if it works. 2. ASUS have a lot of strange options in BIOS/EFI so try changing options that show some relation to this issue and see how that goes.

Comment: No joy from the kernel param (see message edit).  I've poked around in the bios a good bit.  I'll look a little more but I'm going to have to call it a night soon.

Comment: No BIOS changes that seem to relate in any way have had any effect.

Comment: I have a similar issue on a Asus STRIX z590-I board with a 10850k, except I find myself having to reset the cmos on every restart - to avoid having a VGA issue indicated on  QLED on the motherboard, did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I (or the people from ubuntu) solved the Problem. (note that im on debian)

I have installed linux-image-5.10.0-1019-oem (Edit: this kernel has a problem with USB audio, better install a later one like https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/kernel/linux-image-5.10.0-1023-oem) which made the console work and resolved the black screen error. It contains a patch for this problem.

To get xorg working, i also had to update xserver-xorg-video-intel libdrm-intel1 intel-media-va-driver i965-va-driver and intel-media-va-driver and the whole xserver to debian testing.

Also, for the intel driver being used, i had to create an xorg.conf.d config file to force it. That may not be required if you have the newer version installed.

vainfo now reports no errors, my browser (vivaldi) complains that i965 does not support the card, but works fine regardless.

for reference, here are my versions:

```
root@cswork:~# dpkg --list | grep intel
ii  intel-media-va-driver:amd64                   21.1.1+dfsg1-1                                   amd64        VAAPI driver for the Intel GEN8+ Graphics family
ii  intel-microcode                               3.20210216.1~deb10u1                             amd64        Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs
ii  libdrm-intel1:amd64                           2.4.104-1                                        amd64        Userspace interface to intel-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libintellij-annotations-java                  17.0.0-1                                         all          transitional package for libjetbrains-annotations-java
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel                      2:2.99.917+git20200714-1+b1                      amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
root@cswork:~# dpkg --list | grep va-dri
ii  i965-va-driver:amd64                          2.4.1+dfsg1-1                                    amd64        VAAPI driver for Intel G45 & HD Graphics family
ii  intel-media-va-driver:amd64                   21.1.1+dfsg1-1                                   amd64        VAAPI driver for the Intel GEN8+ Graphics family
ii  mesa-va-drivers:amd64                         18.3.6-2+deb10u1                                 amd64        Mesa VA-API video acceleration drivers
ii  va-driver-all:amd64                           2.4.0-1                                          amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API -- driver metapackage
```

Comment: Thanks!  One thing I've noticed is that "shutdown -r now" doesn't manage the reboot.  I will keep an eye for that fix.

Comment: Solved my very same problem on Ubuntu 20.04, thanks!

System: Intel Core i3-10100 and an ASRock H510m itx a/c . 
Updating the Bios to 1.6 didn't help, but your suggested OEM Kernel works just fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed with this kernel (and perhaps others as I have not tested) my CPU will only turbo to 4.7ghz (i9 11900k) despite being set for 5.3 in my bios. Turns out the kernel governor is set to powersave which limits it to 4.7. If I use cpupower to switch to the performance governor I get the full 5.3 but it never idles below 5.0. Further I also have tested with iperf and neither 2.5G nic will run at full speed against a known good server and known good cable. I can iperf that server with my 10700k and z490 board with an Asus realtek based 2.5G nic and get full speed. I've not been able to get another kernel working. Can't seem to boot into mainline kernels after installing this one. I did want to try 5.12 but no dice so far.

EDIT: Not booting into mainline kernels was my user error. As a stop gap I put in a discrete gpu. When I boot the text part of boot comes up on my onboard graphics, then once into the gui login the feed flips to a monitor connected to the discrete gpu. If I try to boot with both monitors attached to onboard I just get a blinking cursor after the boot up text. Anyway I can confirm that mainline kernel 5.12 and 5.11 do NOT solve the igpu issue, CPU governor issue, or onboard 2.5gb NIC issues. So I would say that at least for a video solution stick to the OEM kernel for now. If you want the CPU speed you can work around it by using cpupower to change the governor to "performance". I will continue to update this reply as I find solutions.

Update: Installing updated bios version 0707 for my Asus Rog Strix Z590 motherboard solved the CPU turbo issue. Still stuck on the OEM kernel for my displays to work. I tried 5.12.1 this morning and still no luck.

Comment: Any update on this? I am trying for the past 2 days without any luck.

Comment: Currently running kernel: 5.11.0-23-generic, everything works as it should except I only get 1 gig ethernet. Both monitors work off the motherboard and the turbo issue was fixed by a bios update.