# Black screen on boot without nomodeset

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, nomodeset

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a new build with the following hardware:

- CPU: Intel i5-10400
- Integrated Graphics: Intel UHD 630
- Motherboard: ASRock h510m-ITX/ac
- RAM: Corsair LPX Vengeance 16GB 2666MHz
- SSD: Crucial P2 500GB

I have been unable to get any graphics output to work unless I add `nomodeset` to my kernel parameters - whenever it boots up the screen simply turns off after the ASRock logo, and does not respond to any keyboard input (I can't even switch to a tty).

This includes on the Live USB installer, which I had to run in "safe graphics" mode to install. I have also tried the 20.10 Live USB, and even Manjaro (GNOME 20.2.1), both of which had the same issue.

If I use `nomodeset` then Ubuntu boots normally, but I believe this disables any hardware acceleration, and I'm unable to change the display resolution, so I am looking for a proper fix.

Checking the journal (I can log in via SSH) I see that GDM fails to start:

```
Mar 21 15:20:32 colin-desktop gnome-shell[901]: Failed to create backend: No GPUs with outputs found
Mar 21 15:20:32 colin-desktop gnome-session[830]: gnome-session-binary[830]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Mar 21 15:20:32 colin-desktop gnome-session-binary[830]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Mar 21 15:20:32 colin-desktop gnome-session-binary[830]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
Mar 21 15:20:32 colin-desktop gdm-launch-environment][803]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed for user gdm
Mar 21 15:20:32 colin-desktop gdm3[781]: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
```

And that the Xorg server exits, with error messages from `/var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[     9.404] (EE) modeset(0): No modes.
[     9.406] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[     9.406] (EE)
[     9.406] (EE) no screens found(EE)
[     9.406] (EE)
[     9.406] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[     9.406] (EE)
[     9.407] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

If I enforce the `intel` driver via a configuration file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` then Xorg reports a segmentation fault instead, but the overall effect is the same - no screen!

I have tried various fixes, but none have worked (I'm happy to try these again in case I got something wrong though!):

- Adding i915 and intel_agp to the initramfs (suggested by the Arch Wiki)
- Various configuration options in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
- Updated drivers from ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers and ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
- Installing a newer kernel (5.11)

I would be very grateful for any help that anyone could offer.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome. Since you tried 5.11 do I assume you were running 5.8? If so try 5.4

Comment: Thanks @David! I just tried the 5.4.0 and 5.4.107 mainline kernels, neither worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by installing a recent oem kernel (`linux-image-5.10.0-1019-oem`) which contains a fix for this issue, as suggested in the answer to this question: [Blank (no signal) display on new ASUS Z590 motherboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321469/blank-no-signal-display-on-new-asus-z590-motherboard)

Comment: I am so thankful for your thorough documentation. 

I faced the exact same problem and went through the exact same steps as you with an Intel Core i3-10100 and an ASRock H510m itx a/c . 
Updating the Bios to 1.6 didn't help, but your suggested OEM Kernel works just fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Same here.
I am already using latest ubuntu

```
Linux G7-7588 5.19.0-35-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb 3 18:36:56 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

all gpu status is unclaimed

```
*-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ec000000-ecffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:ed000000-ed07ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:eb000000-ebffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 2
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1080
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iebEp.png)